# VS2010 crashing then restarting after modifying EDMX

Tags: visual-studio-2010, edmx

I've created a RESTful app using Entity Framework 5.1.  It's been stable for a long time.  I recently added a table to my SQL 2005 database and tried adding it to the edmx file for the project.  The table shows up in the designer, but when I go to save the edmx, it causes VS2010 to shutdown then restart.  When it restarts, the table is in the designer, but there are no code templates in the Model.tt folder, and I get a ton of errors when I rebuild the project.

When VS restarts, a system application exception is thrown by devenv.exe.  The first couple of lines are:

> Application: devenv.exe
>   Framework Version: v4.0.30319
>   Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
>   Exception Info: System.AccessViolationException
>      at EnvDTE.ProjectItem.get_FileNames(Int16)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating489EEB6F04CC6591BD374BC5954BE8E5.GeneratedTextTransformation+EntityFrameworkTemplateFileManager+VsEntityFrameworkTemplateFileManager.ProjectSync(EnvDTE.ProjectItem, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1)

Removing the added table doesn't fix the problem, only restoring the project from the previous night's backup gives me clean compiles.

Nothing else seems to be wrong. Any hints or solutions would be appreciated.

Comment: Show us the essential diff between the original en modified file, Did you try the same thing in VS2015 or VS2017?

Comment: I don't have VS2015 or 17 installed.  I did find another post here of the exact same problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14820874/4340328?sem=2), but there were no responses to his question.  I think a key is the cause was "System.AccessViolationException", but I'm clueless what would all of a sudden be causing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did an extensive Google search for similar problems and except for the one mentioned in my comment above, none seem to match.  Since the last time I successfully added a table, I had installed GitHub extensions to VS2010. Grasping at straws, removed the extensions thinking that might have caused the problem, but, alas, the same behavior continued after removal.

I created a new, stripped down project and tried to add a single table to the edmx with the exact same results, VS2010 restarted with the same error in the Windows Application log. When VS2010 restarted, the .cs generated file was listed in the solution explorer under the project, but it was dimmed, i.e. not included in the project. If I manually included it and compiled the project, all went well. but the .cs file was free-floating in the list of project items, not in the .tt folder.

I suppose I could of proceeded, but my confidence was shaken about the integrity of the VS2010 installation.

Out of desperation, I decided to do a maintenance repair of VS2010 Premium.  That took about two hours.  However, .**that fixed the problem**.  I can now add tables and save the emdx and have the .cs class show up under the .tt folder. Everything compiles fine.  Seems like I'm back in business.